# How to install Cocos2d PROJECT templates in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

I've probably googled this question in 20 different syntaxes and I can't find the answer. PLEASE HELP!!! How do I install the Cocos2d project templates in xcode 4? I've tried different ways, but they still don't show up when I build a new project in Xcode 4! HELP!

Comment: Try Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com), it has plenty of template projects (http://www.kobold2d.com/x/8gUO) that can be created with a GUI tool (http://www.kobold2d.com/x/XwMO).

Comment: Which version is need to download cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5 or cocos2d-iphone-1.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The templates have already been published:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13782/page/2#post-82267

Answer (score 12):

[Download **"cocos2d-iphone"** from This Link.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download)

**And follow instructions in Pics.**[image: First step]
[image: Second Step][image: Final Step]

Comment: I just used this method to install Cocos2d 2.1 in Xcode 5, and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't yet. The author of cocos-2d has said that Xcode 4 is not supported yet, a new version should be out shortly with support.

> What’s next:
>
> v1.0-rc in 3~4 weeks: It will includes
>   fixes, fixes, fixes, and Xcode 4
>   templates

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1404

Comment: I just googled Game Engine for Xcode 4 and clicked the link that referred to Cocos2d and was on the Cocos2d website. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The project templates are available now. The file templates are not as of this post.

Answer (score 1):

For file template you could do the following for now:

1. Download "cocos2d_1.0.0.zip" from https://files.me.com/miroslav.perovic/7despc
2. copy the “cocos2d 1.0.0.zip″  to /Developer/Library/XCode/Templates/File templates and unpack it

PS This is not official cocos2d template files.