# Cocos2d install

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode3.2

I tried to install cocos2d framework to my xcode but I can't. I have **Xcode version 3.2.5**,  **cocos2d framework version 0.99.5**, and **iOS version 4.2**.

I opened the terminal and entered

```
$ sudo /mac2/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.3/install-templates.sh
```

Terminal asks me for my password and I enter it. Everything seems going well; the terminal displayed "done". When I open Xcode, I do not see any cocos2d project in user templates (I do not see **user template** section in the new project list).What is the problem?

Comment: duplicate with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287081/how-to-install-cocos2d-project-templates-in-xcode-4

Comment: Try Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com), it has an installer that does this job for you. Kobold2D includes cocos2d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo ./install-templates.sh
```

means to install for system wide. The template would appear in the system wide section.

For as user template, use -u option.

```
./install-templates.sh -u
```

Comment: still nothing appear 
i do not know who i can install this framework to my xcode !!

Comment: I downloaded the stable version. how can I install the file.

Comment: The latest version includes install-templates.sh file in the top of folder of the archive.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of :

[How to install Cocos2d PROJECT templates in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287081/how-to-install-cocos2d-project-templates-in-xcode-4)

The solution is that you have to get the latest from github in order to get xcode 4 templates.

The solution link is here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13782/page/2#post-82267

The github link is:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone.git

I just verified this works.

Answer (score 1):

I only use ./install-templates.sh -u -f and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

In finder, go to your hard drive,

Go to Developer => Library and drag the cocos2d folder into this folder,

Next, open terminal, type cd , and drag the cocos2d folder into the terminal window.

Now do sudo ./install-templates.

That should work.

After, restart xcode.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but still the result of **sudo** command show that everything is good and when i open the **xcode** i **i don not see the user template section**

Answer (score 0):

sudo ./install-templates.sh -u -f
Don't forget the -f

Comment: current version (1.0.0) will not let you run with both sudo and -u.  "Either use the '-u' option or run it as root, but not both options at the same time."